# Python slicing twice in string

Tags: python

```py
message = "Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope."
message = message[8:][:-22]
print(message[8:], end="")
```

**result:** Kenobi

Is it the order is from left to right and after first [:] it will return the result for next [:]?
any document state that it will return the result for the second [:] ?

Comment: `message[8:]` returns the string from index 8 onwards and `[:-22]` gives you _that_ up (but not including) the 22nd-to-last index. It would be better to just do `message[8:-22]` though.

Comment: [8:] indicates you want to start the string from 8th index position (index 0 is the first position). The -22 says you want to stop at 22nd position from the back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: @Moosefeather two [:] can combine into one?

Comment: The answers are more interesting than the question. All of them. What a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the action in multiple steps.

First: the whole string

`"Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope."`

Second. Slice the string from `8` onwards. Results in:

`"Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope."`

Third. Slice the result from `22` from the end. Results in:

`"Obi-Wan Kenobi"`

And finally, when you print you are slicing again, so a 4th step:

`"Kenobi"`

So you can see that the multiple square brackets don't necessarily mean multiple dimensions, but rather chained actions, each being performed on the result from the last.

In arrays of arrays this has the effect of accessing your value, in strings it just means slicing in more places.

Answer (score 2):

`message[8:]` returns all elements from the 8th position from the left-hand side of the `message` onwards.

```
>>> message[8:]
"Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope."
```

`message[8:][:-22]` returns all elements from the 22nd position from the right-hand side of the `message[8:]` (`"Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope."`) onwards.

```
>>> message[8:][:-22]
"Obi-Wan Kenobi"
```

So, if print `message[8:]` again, it will return all elements from 8th position from the left-hand side of `"Obi-Wan Kenobi"` onwards which is `"Kenobi"`.

Answer (score 2):

- `message[8:]` means you are taking the string from 9th char to end of the string. `Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.`
- `message[8:][:-22]` then you perform second slice `[:-22]`-ve index means you are slicing the string from the end. Here, string is sliced which takes all the char leaving 22 chars from the end.  `Obi-Wan Kenobi`
- so your string after  `message[8:][:-22]` becomes `Obi-Wan Kenobi`.
- At last while printing you are slicing the string again `print(message[8:], end="")` which takes `Obi-Wan Kenobi` and slice it such that it takes all the chars in the string from the 9th char, which is `Kenobi`

Answer (score 0):

[`8:]` is from where the slicing begins. `[:-22]` is till when the slicing is to be done, the `-22` indicates that it should be sliced 22 positions backwards from the last index.